# Javascript adding <script> tag after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got a little problem here. Basically, I'm trying to add a script tag after the page loads.

This is what I am doing:

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   function getad()
   {
        $.post('assets/getad.php', "ad", function(response) {
            response = response.replace('document.write','document.getElementById("ad").innerHTML = ');
            eval(response);
            console.log(response);
        });
   }
   getad();
   </script>    
<div id="ad"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

getad.php:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://ads1.qadabra.com/t?id=a823aca3-9e3c-4ddd-a0cc-14b497cad85b&size=300x250");
?>
```

You can find a demo here: http://dev.cj.gy/game/

As you can see, the #ad div DOES get filled with the correct script tag, but it doesnt actually run, If I edit the page to include the script tag right at page load, it does run.

Comment: This would seem an ideal place to use [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), since you appear to be using it already.

Comment: The thing about that is, I am modifying the script before I run (eval) it. I am changing document.write to just set the HTML to ad. The response is also dynamic, so the script changes every time.

Comment: But the `success` callback should be able to deal with that, I would have thought? But rather than do the same replacement on every load/call it'd seem wiser to simply rewrite the JS or php you're calling to provide the script.

Comment: _“As you can see, the #ad div DOES get filled with the correct script tag”_ – nope, I don’t see that. Debugging this in Firebug, I see your script reach the line with `$.post` – but the net panel does not show any post request being made, and the callback function does not seem to get executed either (break point on first line of it never gets reached) … and `#ad` stays empty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `<script>` tags cause execution when parsed as part of the main document; they don't execute from being written to `innerHTML`.

You can create an executing script element outside of that initial parse using the DOM method of calling `createElement('script')`, setting its `src`/content and adding it to the document. This is what jQuery's `getScript` does.

However it wouldn't do you much good because the next script, that `ads1.qadabra.com` is `document.write`ing to the page, also itself calls `document.write`.

You could work your way around both of these calls at the client side (ie without `getad.php`), by assigning your own custom function to `document.write` that, instead of writing to the loading page, attempts to extract the source of the script tag passed to it, and load that in a DOM-created script element.

But in general these are scripts designed to work synchronously at document load time; anything you do to try to force them to run in a way they weren't intended to is likely to be fragile and stop working when the ad network change anything.

If you want to load a third-party ad without pausing the loading of the parent document, I suggest putting it in an iframe.

Comment: I am completley replacing document.write, so thats not a problem... How would i go about creating a new DOM?

Comment: `var s = document.createElement('script'); s.src = extracted_script_url; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s)` or in jQuery `$.getScript(extracted_url)`. But I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: I have actually tried just that, the DOM stuff, still ins't working, just places the ad code into <div ad>. Look here: http://dev.cj.gy/game/

Comment: Works for me, although you shouldn't rely on the `<div>` necessarily being loaded before the callback happens.

Comment: It's loading the ad for you, in the game div tag?

Comment: It loads an ad script, which may or may not work depending on what the ad is. Some ads are coming up with their own use of `document.write` which will naturally fail. Also Yahoo seem to be serving some ad scripts as text/plain which is sad.

Comment: The thing is, if I staticly put the script tag in there before the page loads, it works fine...

Comment: Yes, putting a script tag in loads it inline in the page and in this context the `document.write` method will work. Running outside of the model is not supported by your ad network. Even if you patched `document.write` out completely with some workaround implementation you'd never have any guarantee it would work with all possible ad scripts. Again I would suggest running a plain script tag in an iframe.