# JSONP request linked to user input field+button: only executes once

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, input, jsonp

beginner here, been scouring the web trying to find whether this question has been asked before, but no luck.

I've been trying to create a JSONP request to wikipedia which is linked to a user input field on my page, activated by a button i.e. a search field. It fires off fine the first it's used after page load (returns the numerical page id), but thereafter it doesn't overwrite the response variable if I try to search again...

Thanks in advance for your help!

ps - preferably I would like to avoid using jQuery if possible and stick to pure JS, thanks.

Code is here:

```
var x = document.getElementById("test");
var y = document.getElementById("loadResults");
var wikiResponse;
var script = document.createElement("script");
var userInput;

function launchSearch () {
  if (document.body.contains(script)) {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
  }
  script.src = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=" + userInput + "&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&indexpageids=1&format=json&callback=loadResults"; 
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function loadResults(response) {
 wikiResponse = response.query.pageids[0];
 x.textContent = wikiResponse;
}

y.addEventListener("click", function() {
  userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  launchSearch();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The script you are creating is only executed if it is created by `createElement`, not if it is removed from the body and then added again using `appendChild` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621795/javascript-adding-script-tag-after-page-loads)).

Instead, try creating the element (using `createElement`) every time you want to do the load instead of removing the element from the DOM and re-adding it again.